# Get info from website using requests.get and lxml

Tags: python, request, lxml

so I am trying to make an easy program to look at upvotes and stuff from reddit but my code returns : `[]` instead of what I want it to return.

```py
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/j8u0mw/which_colour_can_fuck_right_off/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
upvotes = tree.xpath('//span[@class="_1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO"]/text()')
print(upvotes)
```

Edit: My expected result would be the amount of upvotes on this post so for this post that'd be: `"51.7k"`.

Comment: The property might be being filled by JS - which won't run during `requests.get`

Comment: You can try to change `www.` to `old.` and get the information from there: `https://old.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/j8u0mw/which_colour_can_fuck_right_off/`

Comment: @JMiller Hi welcome to stackoverflow. Could you actually give a lot more detail about your expected results? Like you want "upvotes and stuff" and its really not clear at all for those that aren't keen on this exact topic what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your xpath expression to

```
//div[@data-test-id="post-content"]//button/following-sibling::div/text()
```